# Create UML class diagram from C# or Java or XML

Tags: uml, class-diagram, tool-uml

We would like to create UML class diagram from relational database tables, C# code, Jave code, or XML.

We tried using NClass as suggested by experts here but didnt help. Though we succeed most of the things required but we are unable to create composition or aggregation between classes.  We tried doing in NClass but we get only association relation instead. Their wiki page shows  that feature is not supported yet. So we are looking for different tools or solution.

is there any other tool that can be used for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enterprise Architect from Sparx Systems](http://www.sparxsystems.com/) can reverse-engineer database schemas, XML schemas, source code in C#, Java and half a dozen additional languages, as well as byte and binary code. It can even generate sequence diagrams after being attached to a running process like a debugger.

The license is commercial, but the price is pretty low (depending on which edition you want) and there are academic discounts. You can also download a fully-featured 30-day evaluation license, so if you only need to do this once you won't have to pay anything.

You should be aware, however, that there are no standardized UML profiles for the different programming languages; the exact representation of various code constructs is tool-specific. In other words, whether you will get compositions, aggregations, associations etc for a given code base depends on which tool you use.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that a lot of tools are able to do that (or part of that ...) so do you have more requirements? For example Do you want an unique tool, many tools (free, open, commercial) ? Do you want to share your model between team menbers?
[Modelio](http://www.modelio.org/) seems able to do that, but I never used the C# and database extension mainly because they are not free ...